# Display two maps with directions on the same web page using Google Maps JavaScript API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display two maps with directions on the same web page using the Google Maps JavaScript API but only one of the maps loads with the directions displayed.

```
<div id = "car_map" style = "width:400px; height:450px;"></div>
<div id = "bus_map" style = "width:400px; height:450px;"></div>

<script  type="text/javascript" >
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('car_map'), {
    zoom:7,
    center: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>}, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bus_map'), {
    zoom:7,
    center: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map2);

  var carRequest = {
    origin: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>}, 
    destination: {lat: <%=@destination[0]%>, lng: <%=@destination[1]%>},
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  var busRequest = {
    origin: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>}, 
    destination: {lat: <%=@destination[0]%>, lng: <%=@destination[1]%>},
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
  };

  directionsService.route(carRequest, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

  directionsService.route(busRequest, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

</script>
```

I have noticed that if I change the the order of the following lines:

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(map2);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

Now map will display the directions and map2 will be a map centered around the specified coordinates but with no directions.  I read online that you have to have unique DirectionsRenderer for each map but I tried creating additional variables and calling them on the different maps but that also did not work.  In fact, when I changed the variable name from var directionsDisplay to var directionsDisplay2 it would not work at all.  Below is the code with those variables added:

```
<div id = "car_map" style = "width:400px; height:450px;"></div>
<div id = "bus_map" style = "width:400px; height:450px;"></div>

<script  type="text/javascript" >
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay2 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('car_map'), {
    zoom:7,
    center: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>}, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bus_map'), {
    zoom:7,
    center: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay2.setMap(map2);

  var carRequest = {
    origin: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>}, 
    destination: {lat: <%=@destination[0]%>, lng: <%=@destination[1]%>},
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  var busRequest = {
    origin: {lat: <%= @origin[0]%>, lng: <%= @origin[1]%>}, 
    destination: {lat: <%=@destination[0]%>, lng: <%=@destination[1]%>},
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
  };

  directionsService.route(carRequest, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

  directionsService2.route(busRequest, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

</script>
```

I would appreciated any advice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You only have one origin/destination array, so both maps look exactly the same. Solve this by making them different.
2. If you get an error in the directions request it silently fails. Solve this by adding a notification in the case of an error.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j5kqbyae/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var origin = [40.7127837, -74.0059413];
var destination = [40.735657, -74.1723667];


var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay2 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('car_map'), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: {
    lat: origin[0][0],
    lng: origin[0][1]
  },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bus_map'), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: {
    lat: origin[1][0],
    lng: origin[1][1]
  },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay2.setMap(map2);

var carRequest = {
  origin: {
    lat: origin[0],
    lng: origin[1]
  },
  destination: {
    lat: destination[0],
    lng: destination[1]
  },
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

var busRequest = {
  origin: {
    lat: origin[0],
    lng: origin[1]
  },
  destination: {
    lat: destination[0],
    lng: destination[1]
  },
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
};

directionsService.route(carRequest, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    alert("car directions failed: " + status)
  }
});

directionsService2.route(busRequest, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay2.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    alert("bus directions failed: " + status)
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#car_map,
#bus_map {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="car_map" style="width:400px; height:450px;"></div>
<div id="bus_map" style="width:400px; height:450px;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! By adding the exact same address to an array twice and referencing it like you did above worked.  I am a little confused on why this is the case.  Both maps should look exactly the same with the only difference being the transit option that is specified in the car/busRequest variable.  Can you elaborate on what is going on? @geocodezip

Comment: Works for me with both sources/destinations the same.  Maybe you were at a location that didn't return transit results.

Comment: It works for me as well, I just want to know why I have to specify the same location twice in an array if I am assigning two different instances of an object to the coordinates.  Why can I not just reference the coordinates multiple times in the code without duplicating them in an array? @geocodezip

Comment: Don't know. I updated both the code snippet and fiddle to use the same coordinates, it works.  So the first issue isn't an issue, must be the second (no transit directions available at those locations).

Comment: Strange, I just changed my code back and it is working for me as well.  I must have had a typo or something because I thought I tried that exact code.  Either way, it is working now.  Thanks a lot for the feedback! @geocodezip